# Fetch Minimal Record with Probability

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I have three records. the records means intervals,

1. $A: [1, 5]$
2. $B: [2, 6]$
3. $C: [4, 6]$

A, B and C are three humidity sensors. Value of A is between 1 to 5, B is between 2 to 6, and C is between 4 to 6

Assume the humidity data is **uniform distributed**(uniform distribution).  I'd like to know which sensor would give the minimal value(lowest humidity), with probability.

Comment: You might want to elaborate slightly.

Comment: Are those points or intervals? What does "minimal data" mean? You tagged this with "uniform-distribution" but have not mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @Henry I've edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the minimum falls in the ranges $[1,2)$ or $[2,4)$ or $[4,5]$ so the probabilities A, B or C give the minimum respectively are

$$\int_{a=1}^2 \frac{da}{5-1}\cdot1\cdot1 + \int_{a=2}^4 \frac{da}{5-1} \cdot \frac{6-a}{6-2} \cdot 1 + \int_{a=4}^5 \frac{da}{5-1}\cdot \frac{6-a}{6-2}\cdot\frac{6-a}{6-4}$$

$$0 + \int_{b=2}^4 \frac{5-b}{5-1}\cdot \frac{db}{6-2}\cdot 1 + \int_{b=4}^5\cdot \frac{5-b}{5-1} \frac{db}{6-2}\cdot\frac{6-b}{6-4}$$

$$0 + 0 + \int_{c=4}^5 \frac{5-c}{5-1}\cdot \frac{6-c}{6-2}\cdot\frac{dc}{6-4}$$

and if you calculate these they should add up to $1$.

Comment: since they are all uniform distribution, I think I can get the value of these expressions, right?

Comment: @Jun1st: One of the integrals is of a constant, two of linear function and three of a quadratic function.

Comment: to the probability of A between [2, 4), I understand the da/(5-1), but not (6-a)/(6-2), why? on my understanding, A has 50% chance between [2, 4), B has 50% change between [2,4). they are independent, so either one has 25% chance to be the minimal value

Comment: If $A=a$ in $[2,4)$ then the probability $B$ is greater is $\dfrac{6-a}{6-2}$

Comment: I think the probability for B is greater is (6-4)/(6-2)

Comment: If for example $a=3$, the probability B is greater than $3$ is $\frac{6-3}{6-2}=\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: these data are continuous, not discreet, So I think it make no sense to pick a single value(3) as an sample. And in a continuous interval, the probability of a single value should be 0

Comment: I think I get it now, and you are right.